# How to configure inplace deployment of gradle project in intellij idea ultimate?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, intellij-14

**Problem:** 
I am using Intellij Idea Ultimate latest (as of now 2017.3.3) for my gradle web project. I have used Gradle Web Artifact (exploded) for this. Now since gradle copy task is not incremental and this project is quite big it takes lot of time to copy files and initial deployment of project is very very slow (30-50 mins).

Intellij Idea docs suggest that [In place deployment](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-an-in-place-server-configuration.html) can solve this problem and help me do more programming than just waiting for the completion of "Copying files ... " task.

When I searched more about it I found there are ways to use [inplace deployment of Maven](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206873265-How-to-configure-Intellij-with-inplace-Tomcat-deployment-) projects. What is the best way to use in place deployment of gradle web project in Intellij Idea Ultimate ?